# Improve Reading performance of large JSON File

Tags: python, json, performance

I am not a IT engineer but Mechanical engineer so do not hesitate to ask me for more details.

I have a huge amount of Magic The Gathering card and wrote a program to read the card from a picture via OpenCV. It treat the picture, extract the name of the card, search for it in JSON file and append it into my library.

[image]

I try to optimize the reading of the JSON file as it go through all possible to match the detected name of the card from the pictures. The Json file gathering all the data is about 210Mo and available online at https://mtgjson.com/downloads/all-files/

In example below, considering already a card name extracted in variable "keyVal" it takes about 10 seconds :

```
import json
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

keyVal ="Arc électrique"

json_file = open("AllPrintings.json", "r", encoding="utf-8")
bdd = json.load(json_file)   

for item in bdd["data"]:
    for card in bdd["data"][item]["cards"]:
        for langue in card["foreignData"]:
            if similar(langue["name"],keyVal) > 0.85:
                print(langue["name"],card["name"], card["type"], card["artist"], bdd["data"][item]["name"], card["number"], card["identifiers"]["multiverseId"])
            if similar(card["name"], keyVal) > 0.85:
                print(card["name"], card["type"], card["artist"], bdd["data"][item]["name"],
                      card["number"], card["identifiers"]["multiverseId"])
```

My first intent was to read the Json file and record only the data I need but it turned into a very very huge file...

Do you have any idea on how improve the research timing ?

Thanks and do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Do you have to read the JSON file each time you want to do a search? If that is not the case, read JSON file once (aka. save it inside the memory) and do your search as nuch as you want. Since the JSON file converted to Python dictionary, search time is O(1) most of the time.

Comment: Thanks @DogukanAltay. What would be the way to do this ?
In my global program, I read the JSON once in a variable that I call in my reading function. Is it what you mean ?

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I think what you want is only the card names, and maybe a way to map that back to the rest of the card info. I think if you're only going over the card names, you'll have to iterate over a lot less data to find a match. That being said, it's still not ideal to iterate over every item in the JSON to find a match for `keyVal`. You might be able to get away with only using Python.I think ideally you want something that can support full text search, like elasticsearch or lucene

Comment: The best way to approach this is to use the proper tool for accessing large amounts of data - a database. JSON is fine for transporting data (such as downloading it) or archiving data, it's not great for accessing data. Instead of banging on the JSON to make it faster, add an intermediary step that converts it into an SQL database table (Python's built-in `sqlite3` is more than adequate as a DB engine, no need to install any extra dependencies) and then change your main program to look up data there.

Comment: Looking at your link, they already provide an SQLite database for download! That's convenient. Ditch the JSON, use that instead.

Comment: Thanks EhteshChoudhury and @Tomalak for you comments.
I will try using SQL instead and measure the performance delta. I don't know yet how to use SQL in Python but it will come :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your program, translated to an SQL-based approach using Python's own `sqlite3` and the SQLite database that https://mtgjson.com/downloads/all-files/ conveniently already offers:

```
import sqlite3
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

conn = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\Tomalak\Downloads\AllPrintings.sqlite")
conn.create_function("SIMILAR", 2, similar)

def find_similar_cards(key_val):
    return conn.execute("""
        SELECT
            c.number, c.name, c.type, c.artist, c.multiverseId,
            fd.name AS local_name, fd.language
        FROM
            cards AS c
            INNER JOIN foreign_data AS fd ON fd.uuid = c.uuid
        WHERE
            SIMILAR(fd.name, ?) > 0.85
    """, [key_val])

for row in find_similar_cards("Arc électrique"):
    print(row)
```

You can see that it's instantly a lot more obvious when reading it, so that's already a big plus.

SQLite allows importing user-defined functions and makes them available for use in SQL queries, so I have imported the `SequenceMatcher`.

Unfortunately, this is also the culprit. It has to scan through each one of the 237,000 records in `foreign_data` and analyze each `name` for its similarity value. This is slow, and not a whole lot can be done about it. On my (older) Laptop it takes a little over 10 seconds to complete this query and print

```
('97', 'Arc Lightning', 'Sorcery', 'Seb McKinnon', '386478', 'Arc électrique', 'French')
('97', 'Arc Lightning', 'Sorcery', 'Seb McKinnon', '394068', 'Arc électrique', 'French')
('174', 'Arc Lightning', 'Sorcery', 'Andrew Goldhawk', '5733', 'Arc électrique', 'French')
```

But there is room for optimization. The `foreign_data` table only contains 160,000 distinct names. It would be possible to create a helper table with those unique names that is faster to scan through, and then join back to the `cards` table. But no matter what you do, searching for "fuzzy" values will always take some time.

In general, the options to improve search times are

- reduce the work load (i.e. work on a table with fewer records, such as "distinct names only")
- use a faster comparison mechanism (i.e. switch from SequenceMatcher to something else)
- use pre-calculated results (not suitable for all situations, for example not in this case)
- possibly: use a full-text index ([SQLite supports that](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html). It might take some time to wrap your head around it, but could be worth it in the end. Full text indexes are very fast and reasonably "fuzzy")

Apart from that, the downloaded SQLite DB has no indexes defined at all, depending on what kind of data you query often, there is room for improvement here, too.

As soon as you're not searching for calculated values, and proper indexes are in place, this will be blazing fast.

Comment: @Flyghost For comparison - when I search with `WHERE fd.name = ?` instead of `WHERE SIMILAR(fd.name, ?) > 0.85`, the search result is instant.

Comment: It is now something like 4 seconds treatmen :-)
I will analyze your code to learn from it !

Comment: @Flyghost Nice! And this is before any optimizations. There is quite some room for experiments here. Get a tool for working with SQLite databases (a prominent one is https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and start playing around.

Comment: Yes you are right. It seams that SequenceMatcher is really taking a lot. I rerun the old code without it and I drop down to 2-3 seconds.
But as the name extrated from OpenCV is most of the time slightly different I need to use this SequenceMatcher :-/

Comment: Not necessarily. There might be other comparison algorithms that perform better. And the full-text index option is definitely worth exploring, too.

Answer (score 1):

I did two things based on you answer @Tomalak.
I created and saved a dedicated table in sqlite bdd using sqlitebrowser and this code only with the data I need:

```
CREATE table res AS SELECT
    c.number, c.name, c.artist, fd.name AS local_name, fd.language, st.name as local_print
FROM
    cards AS c
    LEFT JOIN foreign_data AS fd ON fd.uuid = c.uuid
    LEFT JOIN sets AS st ON st.code = c.setCode
WHERE
    fd.language IS NULL OR fd.language = "French"
```

Then, I called it in python using FTS4 and doing successively two requests to measure the virtual table initialisation timing with a request and then the timing of a single request using same virtualtable:

```
import sqlite3
import time
init = time.time()

keyVal ="Act of Treason"

conn = sqlite3.connect(r"AllPrintings.sqlite")
conn.create_function("SIMILAR", 2, similar)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mtgsearch''')
cur.execute('''CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mtgsearch USING fts4(number, name, artist, namefr, language, local_print)''')
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO mtgsearch(number, name, artist, namefr, language, local_print) SELECT c.number AS number, c.name AS name, c.artist AS artist, c.local_name AS namefr, c.language AS language, c.local_print AS local_print FROM res AS c''')
conn.commit()

stock = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM mtgsearch WHERE name= ?''',[keyVal])


for row in stock:
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])


print(time.time() - init)
init = time.time()

keyVal= "Air Elemental"
stock = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM mtgsearch WHERE name= ?''',[keyVal])

for row in stock:
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])

print(time.time() - init)
```

Results are mindblowing compared to previously ==> first result in 0.4 sec, second result in 0.015 seconds.

If I use Sequencematcher, first request in 1.7 sec and second one in 1.3. So next target is to find a way to improve a faster similarity algorithm. Any ideas ?

Thanks anyway for the help, I learned a lot about SQLite. I did not know anything about writing first post.

Comment: I managed to find an alternative to Sequencematcher which is fuzzywuzzy.
I needed to install also python-Levenshtein-wheels to get the best of it. Now the processing time is about 0.5 seconds.
Mission complete. Thanks all.

Comment: Just wondering, how are you using `SequenceMatcher` and `fuzzywuzzy` with SQLite?

Comment: You can use it as proposed by Tomalak in a previous answer using conn.create_function("SIMILAR", 2, similar).